# need to check to see which variable has highest number

Tags: javascript, wordpress

A colleague and I have this typeform-like questionnaire on a WordPress theme and we are trying to figure out the appropriate javascript logic to check to see which variable has the highest number.

```
<div class="content-area">
+  <main class="subpage-content">
+    <div class="medium-wrapper">
+
+      <?php
+      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
+
+        the_content();
+
+      endwhile; // End of the loop.
+      ?>
```

This is the form that the end user fills out.

```
+      <form id="pool-selector">
+
+        <section id="pool-size" class="pool-question">
+          <div class="question">
+            <h3>What is the size of your yard?</h3>
+          </div>
+          <div class="answer-choices">
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="small-pool">Small</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="small-pool" name="pool-size" type="radio" value="1"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="medium-pool">Medium</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="medium-pool" type="radio" name="pool-size" value="2"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="large-pool">Large</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="large-pool" type="radio" name="pool-size" value="3"/>
+            </div>
+          </div>
+        </section>
+
+        <section id="family-size" class="pool-question">
+          <div class="question">
+            <h3>How big is your family?</h3>
+          </div>
+          <div class="answer-choices">
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="single-person">Single</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="single-person" name="family-size" type="radio" value="0"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="couple">Couple</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="couple" type="radio" name="family-size" value="2"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="small-family">Small Family</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="small-family" type="radio" name="family-size" value="0"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="large-family">Large Family</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="large-family" type="radio" name="family-size" value="p"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="extended-family">Extended Family</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="extended-family" type="radio" name="family-size" value="p"/>
+            </div>
+          </div>
+        </section>
+
+        <section id="pool-use" class="pool-question">
+          <div class="question">
+            <h3>How do you picture yourself using your perfect pool?</h3>
+            <span>(Select all that apply.)</span>
+          </div>
+          <div class="answer-choices">
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="swimming-laps">Swimming laps to stay in shape</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="swimming-laps" name="pool-use-1" type="checkbox" value="e"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="relaxing">Relaxing with a cool drink after a long day</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="relaxing" type="checkbox" name="pool-use-2" value="r"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="group-play">Playing water sports with family and friends</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="group-play" type="checkbox" name="pool-use-3" value="p"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="neighborhood-hangout">The go-to place for kids in the neighborhood</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="neighborhood-hangout" type="checkbox" name="pool-use-4" value="p"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="adult-social">Throwing social gatherings with an adult drink or two</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="adult-social" type="checkbox" name="pool-use-5" value="t"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="quick-dip">Quick dip to cool off after sunbathing</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="quick-dip" type="checkbox" name="pool-use-6" value="r"/>
+            </div>
+            <div class="answer-choice">
+              <label for="water-aerobics">Adding water aerobics to your workout plan</label><br/>
+              <input class="answer-select" id="water-aerobics" type="checkbox" name="pool-use-7" value="e"/>
+            </div>
+          </div>
+        </section>
+
+        <div class="calculate-results clearfix">
+          <h3>All done? Get you pool profile!</h3>
+          <a onclick="findProfile()" class="button button-yellow">Submit</a>
+        </div>
+
+      </form>
```

This is the javascript logic.

```
+      <script>
+        function findProfile() {
+          var poolSize = jQuery('#pool-size .answer-select:checked').val();
+          var familySize = jQuery('#family-size .answer-select:checked').val();
+
+          var relax = 0;
+          var play = 0;
+          var exercise = 0;
+          var party = 0;
+
+          jQuery('.answer-select:checked').each(function() {
+            switch(jQuery(this).val()) {
+              case "r":
+                relax += 1;
+                break;
+              case "p":
+                play += 1;
+                break;
+              case "e":
+                exercise += 1;
+                break;
+              case "t":
+                party += 1;
+                break;
+            }
+          });
+

            //thinking the code should go here
+
+          console.log("Pool Size:" + poolSize);
+          console.log("Family Size:" + familySize);
+        }
+      </script>
+
+    </div>
+  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need the variable name, or are you just looking for the largest value entered?

Comment: @RobertFrenette, I think we do need the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create an object that holds the options, then define a sort function.

```
var options = {
    relax: 0,
    play: 0,
    exercise: 0,
    party: 0,
}

      jQuery('.answer-select:checked').each(function() {
        switch(jQuery(this).val()) {
          case "r":
            options.relax += 1;
            break;
          case "p":
            options.play += 1;
            break;
          case "e":
            options.exercise += 1;
            break;
          case "t":
            options.party += 1;
            break;
        }
      });

var sortable = [];
for (var opt in options) {
    sortable.push([opt, options[opt]]);
}

sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});
```

then sortable will return `[["play", 2], ["party", 5], ..]`